# Java: simple but unusual NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm stuck on something that is usually really simple. I'm getting a NullPointerException when calling this simple class's constructor:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Brick extends ColorShape {
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int yPos = 0;
        private int width = 0;
        private int height = 0;
        private Rectangle2D.Double shape;

        // constructor
        public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));

            //set brick x, y, width, and height
            xPos = x;
            yPos = y;
            width = w;
            height = h;

            // update shape
            shape.setRect((double)xPos, (double)yPos, (double)width, (double)height);
        }

        public int getX() {
            return xPos;
        }

        public Rectangle2D.Double getShape() {
            return shape;
        }
    }
```

It gets called this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {

                // initialize bricks[i][j]
                bricks[i][j].setLocation((double)(i*brickWidth), (double)(j*brickHeight));
                bricks[i][j].setSize((double)brickWidth, (double)brickHeight);
                //bricks[i][j] = new Brick(i*brickWidth, j*brickHeight, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                //bricks[i][j] = new Brick(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

No matter what I try, I always get a NullPointerException trying to initialize that class.

EDIT:

Tristan's suggestions along with changing the nested for loops to the code below fixed it

```
// create new bricks and store them in bricks array
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {


                // initialize bricks[i][j]
                //bricks[i][j].setLocation((double)(i*brickWidth), (double)(j*brickHeight));
                //bricks[i][j].setSize((double)brickWidth, (double)brickHeight);
                bricks[i][j] = new Brick(i*brickWidth, j*brickHeight, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                //bricks[i][j] = new Brick(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: We can't see your parent class, but read into **field hiding**.

Comment: I think numRows and numCols should be swapped. Depending on how it's defined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are accidentally redeclaring shape as an uninitialized field. The shape you are calling `setRect` on has not been initialized the way you think it has.

If you have a shape in the parent class that you are trying to access, simply set its modifier to `protected` and remove the private shape declaration in the class you posted.

```
/* REMOVE THIS */
private Rectangle2D.Double shape; // uninitialized!

// constructor
public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));

    //set brick x, y, width, and height
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    // update shape
    // This now references a protected instance variable inherited from the parent.
    shape.setRect((double)xPos, (double)yPos, (double)width, (double)height);
}
```

However looking through this constructor, it seems rather off. If it is the case that the parent class has a shape itself, why do you need to set the rectangle any differently than the way you set it in the parent class?

For example, this code ***appears*** to be logically equivalent.

```
// Call the parents constructor to set the shape of this brick..
public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));
}
```

Comment: ok. Just to test it, i changed it to this private Rectangle2D.Double shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,1,1); and still have the same error

Comment: Don't change it to private, just remove it. Does your parent class have an instance variable named shape?

Comment: the code won't execute anything past super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h)); in the constructor.  supre refers to ColorShape.ColorShape(RectangularShape s)

Comment: Maybe there's a good reason for holding onto `int` versions of the dimensions.  It looks like otherwise he'd have to cast `double`s back to `int`s.  Although it would probably take a really big loop before this caused any noticeable performance problems.

Comment: It's possible. Not sure if thats what he is trying to do though :P

Comment: i removed it like you asked. afterwards it complaine that setRect didn't exist so I found something similar // update shape
   shape.setFrame((double)xPos, (double)yPos, (double)width, (double)height); but it still throws the same error

Comment: @user3161533 So far, you haven't told us what line it's getting the `NullPointerException` on.  (I'm not even certain that it's been on the same line every time you've tried it.)  Did you look at the stack trace and find out?

Comment: I removed everything in the constructor but super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h)); The line: super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h)); will not execute and is throwing the exception.

Comment: Did you set the parent class modifier of shape to protected?

Comment: I can't access it. I did get the code to work though. I'll edit the post and mark this answer as soon as I finish editing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Tristan, the problem with the initial brick constructor is that shape has been declared but not instantiated.

That said, it is simple to instantiate shape:

```
public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));

    //set brick x, y, width, and height
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    // update shape
    // This now references a protected instance variable inherited from the parent.
    shape = (Rectangle2D.Double)super.shape;
    shape.setRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);
}
```